# Relationship between connectedness and (co)separators

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

> What is known about the relationship between connectedness and (co)separators?

A category is said to be [connected](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+category) iff it is inhabited and every object is connected by a [zigzag](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zigzag) of morphisms to every other object.

An object $S$ in a category is said to be a [separator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator) iff morphisms out of $S$ are sufficient to delineate between distinct parallel arrows.

Define a disconnected subcategory $B$ of $C$ to be a subcategory $B$ such that there don't exist any zigzags in $C$ between objects in $B$ and objects not in $B$. Note that $C$ is trivially a disconnected subcategory of itself. (perhaps bad terminology, but necessary for the statement of the second lemma to look good)

We easily have the following

> **Lemma.** If $C$ has a separator, the only disconnected subcategories of $C$ are $C$, [thin](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thin+category) or trivial.

For a proof, observe that if $C$ has a nontrivial non-thin disconnected subcategory $B\neq C$ then we would need two separators, one in $B$ and one outside $B$. Thin disconnected subcategories are fine since there are no distinct parallel arrows.

For a category $C$, let $Dis(C)$ denote the class of all nontrivial non-thin disconnected subcategories of $C$ (so $C\in Dis(C)$). If we allow a separating set and take the obvious definition of a 'minimal separating set' then the above lemma generalizes to yield the following

> **Lemma.** If $C$ has a minimal finite separating set $\mathcal{S}$, then $$|Dis(C)|=|S|.$$

I suspect that this generalizes to infinite separating sets in a straightforward manner, but this is all pretty low hanging fruit and I'm sure it's been discovered by other people before now. Has anyone written up notes on the relationship between the two notions, or do any standard references discuss their relationship in detail? Any assistance is appreciated.